# Generalisation of the Liouville function as irreducible representations for the semigroup ($\mathbb{N},\cdot)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory

This is a duplicate of a question I have asked at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581036/generalisation-of-the-liouville-function-as-irreducible-representations-for-natu) at math stack exchange, but I thought it could be also here of interest.

When looking at the [Liouville function] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function), defined as 
$$ \lambda(n) = (-1)^{\Omega_n},$$ where $\Omega_n$ is the total count of prime factors of $n$ (including multiplicity), it occurred to me, that this in a sense parallels an irreducible representation for the multiplicative semigroup of integers since the maps $n\mapsto \Omega_n$ and $n\mapsto\lambda(n)$ are multiplicative, thus homomorphisms. So one could generalise the Liouville function to
$$ \lambda_m(n) =  (e^{i\frac{2\pi}{m}})^{\Omega_n \mathrm{mod}\,m} ,$$
which recovers for $m=2$ the normal Liouville function
$$ \lambda_2(n) = (e^{i\frac{2\pi}{2}})^{\Omega_n \mathrm{mod}\,2} = (-1)^{\Omega_{n} {\mathrm{mod}}\,2} = \lambda(n).$$
In this way one would get other such functions "mimicking" irreducible representations.

The questions are

1. has this analogy been exploited already?
2. are these functions used already?
3. could one show the orthogonality $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\overline{\lambda_i(n)}\lambda_j(n)\overset{?}=\delta_{ij}$$
4. what can be said about the asymptotics of the series $$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\overline{\lambda_i(n)}\lambda_i(m)$$ 
   which would correspond to the "column orthogonality" in the character table, and be the order of the centraliser of the (semi?)group for conjugated elements $n,m$ and be $0$ otherwise?

For example for $\lambda_1(n):=1=\lambda_j(n)\;\forall n$ (the "totally symmetric representation") and $\lambda_i(n)=\lambda(n)$, that reduces to $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{L_N}{N},$$ with the Liouville sum function $L_N$. The statement that this limit $=0$ is apparently equivalent to the prime number theorem (while $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{L_N}{N^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}}=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$ is RH). I do not have any experiences with groups of infinte order, but the question if $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_i(n)}{\sqrt{N}}$ or similar converges, seems closely connected with the question if $\lambda_i$ can be normalised and hence if they are "proper" irreducible representations distributed evenly around the unit circle.

Comment: It could be interesting to study the object  $ \tilde{\lambda}_{p} : =(\lambda_{p},\lambda_{p^2},\cdots,\lambda_{p^k},\cdots) $ with maybe some extra structure still to be defined.

Comment: Extra structure could be maybe coded in an additional phase coefficient in the exponential (maybe about the type of prime??)?

Comment: One could try to specify in some way the "primality order" of the considered prime, that is the smallest positive  $ k $ such that  $ \pi^{\circ k}(p) $  is composite.

Comment: The Selberg–Delange method addresses the functions $z^{\omega(n)}$ and $z^{\Omega(n)}$ (indeed, in some sense those are the most natural functions for it to study): one can get an asymptotic formula for their summatory function, which in particular establishes the orthogonality property you suggest. See Tenenbaum's book or Montgomery/Vaughan's book.

Comment: What does it mean to speak of an irreducible representation of a function?  (I assume also that you mean to speak of the multiplicative *semi*group of integers.  Ah, one more:  I should also say that $n \mapsto \Omega_n$ is certainly multiplicative, but not, obviously, an isomorphism.)

Comment: @LSpice: Very good questions, that bring the laymen into trouble :-) I thought that the multiplicative semigroup of integers is abelian and that it then has by the Grothendieck construction a corresponding Grothendieck-group. Regarding the isomorphism then: Is it not correct that a multiplicative map between groups is necessarily an isomorphism?

Comment: I am afraid that if someone asks "Is it not correct that a multiplicative map between groups is necessarily an isomorphism?" then perhaps they should be asking questions on http://math.stackexchange.com rather than this site. Moreover, it makes no sense to talk of a representation of $\Omega_n$ in this context.

Comment: @YemonChoi:  I am sorry (is it wrong?)! OK, maybe I'll better delete the post? For the moment I have adressed this issues, including MSE (except you mean exclusively on MSE).

Comment: For $|z| \le 1$ and $\Re(s)$ large enough $F_z(s) =\prod_p \frac{1}{1-z p^{-s}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_z(n)n^{-s}$. We know how to estimate $\sum_{n \le x} \lambda_z(n)n^{-s}$ using quite the same method as for the prime number theorem. $\lambda_z(n) \lambda_{z_2}(n) = \lambda_{z z_2}(n)$. By the way do you know Dirichlet characters ?  They contain much more number-theoretic information.

Comment: I have just found [this](https://tiwong.github.io/maths/ParityFinal.pdf), their (1.4) is related.

Comment: You are right that the Grothendieck construction produces a group from the multiplicative semi-group of *non-$0$* integers, but this is the group of non-$0$ rationals, and so one wouldn't want to call it the group of integers!  An isomorphism is, in particular, bijective, so a map like your $\Omega$ for which $\Omega_2 = 1 = \Omega_3$ is, though multiplicative, not an isomorphism.  As @YemonChoi says, these terminological difficulties seem to act against your post; but other responses suggest that there is important analytic content here (I'm not in a position to judge), so I wouldn't delete.

Comment: @LSpice: I am very sorry: I mixed up "iso" with "homo". And I guess thats what is required (homomorphism) for a set being a representation of another (semi)group, no? I know I am a very weak layman and I am grateful that you bother to consider this idea. About the Grothendieck construction: This was one of the two possibilities I saw how to save thing; the other one is focussing on semigroups, which apparently can also have irreducible representations. It seem the latter one makes less problems for the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of a question on Math.SE.

Comment: Dear @GregMartin: At the moment I do not have access to the literature you have suggested (I just have ordered Tennenbaum), but just to get sure I did not misunderstand your answer: Is it correct that my suggested orthogonality relation holds, and that the proof for this can be found in the suggested lit.? Or does it mean, that it can be (easily?) deduced from the asymptotic behaviour of the summation function of $z^{\Omega(n)}$, which can be found in the books? Maybe you could elaborate on that and make an answer for (iii), and eventually also (i)+(ii)?

Comment: "easily deduced".

Comment: And then, of course (iv) the asymptotics of series corrsponding to the "column" orthogonality: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{\lambda_i(n)}\lambda_i(m)$ would be of special interest.